# Return Value Function - Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have made this two prolog functions:

```
   move-pacman([[Xpacman,Ypacman]],[[Xghost,Yghost]|_], Listpellets, Movepacman):- Xpacman+1=:=Xghost, Ypacman=Yghost, haspellet(Listpellets, Xpacman-1, Ypacman), Movepacman=0,!.
   move-pacman([[Xpacman,Ypacman]],[[Xghost,Yghost]|_], Listpellets, Movepacman):- Xpacman-1=:=Xghost, Ypacman=Yghost, haspellet(Listpellets, Xpacman+1, Ypacman), Movepacman=1,!.
   move-pacman([[Xpacman,Ypacman]],[[Xghost,Yghost]|_], Listpellets, Movepacman):- Ypacman+1=:=Yghost, Xpacman=Xghost, haspellet(Listpellets, Xpacman-1, Ypacman), Movepacman=2,!.
   move-pacman([[Xpacman,Ypacman]],[[Xghost,Yghost]|_], Listpellets, Movepacman):- Ypacman-1=:=Yghost, Xpacman=Xghost, haspellet(Listpellets, Xpacman+1, Ypacman), Movepacman=3,!.
   move-pacman([[Xpacman,Ypacman]],[_|Restghosts], Listpellets, Movepacman):- move-pacman([[Xpacman,Ypacman]],Restghosts, Listpellets, Movepacman).

   haspellet([[Xpellet,Ypellet]|_], Xpacman, Ypacman):- Xpacman = Xpellet, Ypacman = Ypellet, !.
   haspellet([_|Restpellets], Xpacman, Ypacman):- haspellet(Restpellets,Xpacman,Ypacman).
```

My question is why when I run my programm with this:

```
   move-pacman([[5,6]],[[6,6]],[[4,6]],R).
```

The return value is a boolean instead of an int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have more than a problem in your code.

To begin with, a functor (the 'name' of a procedure, or set of rules), *can* contain the hypen, but then you must quote it. In other words, a functor must be an atom, and not a compound expression:

```
'move-pacman'([[5,6]],[[6,6]],[[4,6]],R).
```

would be the amended syntax, I guess you meant

```
move_pacman([[5,6]],[[6,6]],[[4,6]],R).
```

that's the usual way to write it.

Then about rules: arithmetic must be *explicitly* evaluated, or Prolog will carry on the 'expression syntax tree' and it will not match your intended rules. Then introduce variables like `X1` below

```
move_pacman([[Xpacman,Ypacman]],[[Xghost,Yghost]|_], Listpellets, Movepacman):-
   Xpacman+1 =:= Xghost,
   Ypacman = Yghost,
   X1 is Xpacman-1,
   haspellet(Listpellets, X1, Ypacman),
   Movepacman = 0,
   !.
```

note it's good style to write each 'call' on a separate line...